# Select and declare file structures to meet design storage requirements

Tags: java

If this was a question posted to you about a program you wrote what sort of response would they be looking for, quite a basic understanding coder.

Comment: can you provide more context? it is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: What do you store in your program?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but it seems that you are being asked about what data structures you used that fit the given requirements in order to implement your solution (e.g., a hashtable, tree, etc.)